# Sandboxed Cocoa Application Groups

Tags: cocoa, appstore-sandbox

The entitlement documentation describes a method in which [multiple apps produced by a single development team can share access to a special group container](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19)

I've added the entitlement key to a main application and a helper application that is included in the main application bundle. The group directory is never created, and the method in which to get the path – `[NSURL containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:]` – doesn't actually exist in any header.

What am I missing to create a shared group container?

*UPDATE* : added entitlements and group container creation

Here is my entitlements file for the main app and helper application. (replacing TEAM_ID with my actual ID)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>TEAM_ID.com.pinepointsoftware</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've attempted to create the Group Container directory myself based on some information from the dev forums:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path = [@"~/Library/Group Containers/TEAM_ID.com.pinepointsoftware" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

if ([fm createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL]) {
    [fm createFileAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"] contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

Executing that inside the main and and helper app create two different directories inside their each sandbox.

I found a sample project from Apple *AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo*, that uses the application groups for XPC. I can get it working by changing the entitlements and bundle identifiers to match my team, but cannot get the Group Containers to be shared.

Comment: Can you post an xml plist of what your entitlements declaration looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "~" will be automatically converted to your container directory in a sandboxed environment.

So one way to do it is to append the "~" with a number of step back  ("../") until you reach ~/Library and then you create your group container starting from it.

Comment: Great, thanks. Creating a directory using this worked: `NSString *groupContainer = [@"~/../../../Group Containers/TEAM_ID.com.pinepointsoftware" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];`

Comment: Although that works, I'm worried this might break in the future once Apple fixes it! Strangely the feature was introduced in 10.7.4, it's now 10.8.1 and they still have not addressed this serious bug.

Comment: It's not a bug. If you don't have access to the path, it won't work. It's a workaround to get the path of the group container until the method containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier is implemented.